# Prevent MYSQL users reading status of global variables

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to prevent a user from reading status or global variables via `SHOW VARIABLES;` or `SHOW STATUS;`   the same way it is possible to restrict privileges on reading or acting on a table or database in MySQL?

Comment: Is it "users"?  Or some third-party software that can't seem to remember what is going in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply not possible. According to  [mysql reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-status.html) no privileges are required for `SHOW STATUS;` statement.